# deseo poner fecha en un formulario con laravel

Tags: laravel

//codigo de mi input lo puse de tipo date pero en el value no puedo realizar el manejo de las fechas

```
<div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('Fecha') }}
            {{ Form::date('pos_fecha', $posteado->pos_fecha, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('pos_fecha') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'value' => $fcha = date("m-d-Y"),'disabled']) }}
            {!! $errors->first('pos_fecha', '<div class="invalid-feedback">:message</div>') !!}
```

[image: no se muestran los datos enviados]

Comment: El formato que se le debe dar a las fechas para poder asignarla a un `input type="date"` es `"yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: tienes razon gracias por ese detalle  pero ocurre un probema es que no se muestra en mi sitio la fecha actual solo esta por defecto (mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que los input de tipo `date` admiten las fechas en formato `"yyyy-MM-dd"`,
deberás modificar el formato de la función date(`...`) para que concuerde con este formato que ya te menciono.

Deberás modificar la línea en la que asignas el valor al input tal que:

```
 'value' => date("Y-m-d");
```